# Creating a date range table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm writing a report that needs to display a value per day. I have the start and end date for the query, but I wish to avoid missing days in case the table does not contain a value for a specific date.
I was thinking about creating a base date range table that holds all days between start and end, then left join it with the data table to show a value for each day.

I found a few scripts for mySQL, SQL Server, etc.. but none for SQLite.
Is there a way to quickly populate a table with a date range?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get all dates in date range in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140308/get-all-dates-in-date-range-in-sql-server)

Comment: Thanks @AndriyM, but the thread indicated contains a specific example for implementation using T-SQL on MS SQL Server. Unfortunately (or fortunately, depends who you ask) I'm working with SQLite which means I cannot use the solution indicated.

Comment: I believe something happened to my eyes when I was looking at your question, otherwise I can't explain how I could miss the `sqlite` tag. Sorry. Still, the accepted answer's basic idea is to use a numbers table. Perhaps it could be applied to your situation as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you could use a numbers table to expand a range:

```
SELECT
  datetime('now', N || ' seconds') AS DT
FROM numbers
WHERE N < strftime('%s', 'now', '1 minutes') - strftime('%s', 'now');
```

In this case, the numbers table is supposed to hold numbers starting from 0.

A numbers table is a tool worth keeping handy for many purposes. You could initialise it like this, for instance:

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (N int);
/* #0 */ INSERT INTO numbers (N) SELECT 0;
/* #1 */ INSERT INTO numbers (N) SELECT N + C FROM numbers, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM numbers);
/* #2 */ INSERT INTO numbers (N) SELECT N + C FROM numbers, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM numbers);
/* #3 */ INSERT INTO numbers (N) SELECT N + C FROM numbers, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM numbers);
/* #4 */ INSERT INTO numbers (N) SELECT N + C FROM numbers, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM numbers);
/* #5 */ INSERT INTO numbers (N) SELECT N + C FROM numbers, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM numbers);
/* #6 */ INSERT INTO numbers (N) SELECT N + C FROM numbers, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS C FROM numbers);
/* #… */
```

Every line `#N` results in 2<sup>*N*</sup> rows in the table, the largest number being `2N-1`

A demonstration of the method can be found (and played with) [on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/1050f/5).

Comment: @mr. kav number tables are very use full, see [What is the best way to create and populate a numbers table?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1393951/65223)

Answer (score 0):

it depends the level of details you want.
If you simply want the dates from A until B you can do this:

```
declare @start datetime
set @start = '04/20/2012'
while @start <getdate() begin
  print @start
  set @start = dateadd(dd,1,@start)
end
```

just change the print to a insert on a table.

If you need more details you may need a more elaborate scripts. I can point you to some, just be more specific on your requirements

Comment: Thanks, however I was looking for a query that calculates the dates on the fly to save the iterations processing time. I'm looking to have a second-by-second breakdown of a year for example.