# SQL Query Startdate to Enddate

Tags: sql

I have a table (eg. *TableA*) like this

|   Name    |   Startdate   |   Enddate    |
|----------------------------------------------|
|      a         | 2014-02-26 | 2014-02-28 |
|      b         | 2014-03-05 | 2014-03-06 |

If I want to below results. Please help how to do?

| Name   |       Date      |
|---------------------------|
|     a     | 2014-02-26 |
|     a     | 2014-02-27 |
|     a     | 2014-02-28 |
|     b     | 2014-03-05 |
|     b     | 2014-03-06 |

Thank you.

Comment: Which is your database? sql server, oracle, MySql etc.?

Comment: Make clear your question.... I think u are talking about get result from a start date to end date from column StartDate and EndDate. Use SP to make increment in startdate and check for <=Enddate value

Comment: The question doesn't really state what kind of query you are looking for. From what I can see, you want all the dates between start date and end date for each name. Is that correct?

Comment: ...And do you have a Calendar Table?  If yes, this is trivial.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get all dates in date range in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140308/get-all-dates-in-date-range-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server it can be achieved by using `CTE` as below

```
;WITH cte(name, Startdate,Enddate)
AS
(  
    SELECT name, Startdate,Enddate FROM your_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name, DATEADD(dd, 1,Startdate),Enddate FROM CTE 
    WHERE Startdate < Enddate
)
SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY name
```

Here is the code at [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14cab/2)

Comment: Using recursive CTEs is not a good way to generate a series in SQL Server. Although on this scale it is unlikely to cause much of a problem, this would still be better using set based logic. See - [Generate a set or sequence without loops – part 2](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)

Comment: @GarethD would we consider CTE as a loop? A loop would certainly hamper performance, but as far as my experience goes, CTEs fare very well in performance

Comment: I would consider a recursive CTE a while loop, since it will continue to execute the recursive member while it returns results, although this is semantics. Read the article I posted, or at least scroll down to the performance comparison where it shows a recursive CTE to be over 15 times slower than the next slowest method.

Comment: It is in my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle it's a little tricky:

```
SELECT distinct b.name, trim(regexp_substr(b.dates, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) day
  FROM 
  (
    select a.name name,(select WM_CONCAT(a.startdate + rownum -1)  from all_objects  where rownum <=    a.enddate - a.startdate + 1) dates
    from TableA a
  ) b
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= length(b.dates) - length(REPLACE(b.dates, ',', ''))+1
order by 1,2;
```

The inner query generates days for each name as a comma-separated String. The outer simply splits the String in several rows.

Comment: ....really?  While I don't doubt that this works, it's not likely to be a performant option.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a easy way to do this

```
select name, startdate from test_table
UNION ALL 
select name, enddate from test_table
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: This just gets the start date and the end date, not the dates in between. e.g. for `a` in the sample data this would not include `2014-02-27`