# Monthly grain to a daily grain

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to easily go from a monthly grain to a daily grain? For example, here is a monthly grain table:

```
DECLARE @SessionsPerArea TABLE (idSession INT, startDate DATE)
INSERT  @SessionsPerArea VALUES
(1,'2013-01-31'),
(2,'2013-02-28'),
(3,'2013-03-31')

select *
from @SessionsPerArea
```

Result:

```
idSession   startDate
1   2013-01-01
2   2013-02-01
3   2013-03-01
```

I would like the result to be the following:

```
idSession   startDate
1   2013-01-01
1   2013-01-02
1   2013-01-03
.
.
1   2013-01-30
1   2013-01-31
2   2013-02-01
2   2013-02-01
2   2013-02-02
.
.
2   2013-02-27
2   2013-02-28
3   2013-03-01
3   2013-03-02
3   2013-03-03
.
.
3   2013-03-30
3   2013-03-31
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for.  Do you want to take the data in the `@SessionsPerArea` table, and expand it so that for each `idSession` there is one row for each day of the month that the `startDate` is in?  Also are you assuming that `startDate` is always the first day of the month or how does one know what dates to include?

Comment: @AdamPorad Yes to your first question. About your second question, I made an update. I am assuming that I have idSession for every last day of a month. In other words, StartDate is always last day of a month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested this example on <kbd>[SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3c61e/12)</kbd>. It uses a [recursive](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) [Common Table Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972(v=sql.110).aspx) (CTE) to create a temporary result set that has a record for each day of the month for a given `idSession` and `startDate`.

```
;WITH cteDateTable AS
(
    SELECT idSession, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, MIN(startDate) OVER (PARTITION BY idSession)), 0) as StartDate, Max(startDate) OVER (PARTITION BY idSession) as EndDate
    FROM SessionsPerArea
    UNION ALL

    SELECT idSession, DATEADD(D, 1, StartDate), EndDate
    FROM cteDateTable
    WHERE DATEADD(D, 1, StartDate) <= EndDate
)
SELECT idSession, StartDate 
FROM cteDateTable
ORDER BY idSession, StartDate
```

I got some help from these other SO answers (as well as others I browsed).

- [How can I select the first day of a month in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1520803/21353) Answer by LukeH
- [Get all dates in date range in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9140580/21353) Answer by Joe Daley

Answer (score 0):

It easy and efficient if you use a [table of numbers](http://web.archive.org/web/20141209041043/http://web.archive.org/web/20150411042510/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-numbers-table.html). Here is a good [article](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) describing how to generate it.

For this example I populate it on the fly, but in production I have a permanent table with 100K rows. It is useful in many reports.

```
DECLARE @Numbers TABLE (Number int PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO @Numbers (Number)
SELECT TOP(100) 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sys.all_objects.object_id) AS Number
FROM sys.all_objects;
```

Now for each session we return all days of the month using `CROSS APPLY`. This solution returns all days of the month on or before the `startDate`. If your `startDate` is the last day of the month (as you said it is), then there will be a row for each day of the month.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/73b626/2/0)

```
DECLARE @SessionsPerArea TABLE (idSession INT, startDate DATE)
INSERT  @SessionsPerArea VALUES
(1,'2013-01-31'),
(2,'2013-02-28'),
(3,'2013-03-31')

SELECT *
FROM 
    @SessionsPerArea AS S
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT DATEADD(day, 1-N.Number, S.startDate) AS NewDate
        FROM @Numbers AS N
        WHERE N.Number <= DAY(S.startDate)
    ) AS CA
ORDER BY S.idSession, NewDate;
```

**Result set**

```
idSession    startDate     NewDate
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-01
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-02
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-03
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-04
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-05
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-06
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-07
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-08
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-09
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-10
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-11
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-12
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-13
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-14
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-15
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-16
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-17
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-18
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-19
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-20
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-21
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-22
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-23
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-24
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-25
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-26
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-27
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-28
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-29
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-30
1            2013-01-31    2013-01-31
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-01
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-02
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-03
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-04
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-05
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-06
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-07
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-08
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-09
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-10
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-11
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-12
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-13
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-14
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-15
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-16
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-17
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-18
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-19
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-20
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-21
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-22
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-23
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-24
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-25
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-26
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-27
2            2013-02-28    2013-02-28
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-01
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-02
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-03
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-04
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-05
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-06
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-07
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-08
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-09
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-10
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-11
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-12
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-13
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-14
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-15
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-16
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-17
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-18
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-19
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-20
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-21
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-22
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-23
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-24
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-25
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-26
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-27
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-28
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-29
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-30
3            2013-03-31    2013-03-31
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Vladimir. To be honest I really liked your answer and explanation, but I prefer CTE on cross apply. That's the only reason I picked the other answer. Ny vse ravno spasibo. :)

Comment: No problem. I guess your data set is small, so performance-wise any solution would be OK.